# Cómo borrar elemento de una lista dentro de diccionario

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, diccionarios

Tengo este diccionario con una lista de key "puzzles". Se me pide borrar el elemento "Batman" de esa misma lista, pero no sé cómo hacerlo. He probado del y pop, pero no aplica para este caso.

```
juguetes = {
    'muñecas': 500,
    'juegos': ['Guess who?', 'Clue', 'Battleship'],
    'puzzles': ['Star Wars', 'Batman', 'Ironman']
}
```

¿Alguien podría ayudarme? Gracias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes acceder a la lista en `puzzles` con `juguetes['puzzles']`
y luego eliminar el elemento concreto con `remove()`

Por lo tanto tendría que ser así:

```
juguetes['puzzles'].remove('Batman')
```

Con `pop()` y `del` puedes eliminar un elemento de la lista especificándole su índice.

Comment: Muchas gracias!